# updating xml, using xmlstarlet, with a sequence of letters

Tags: xmlstarlet

When I am having `input.xml`, and want to update it to get `output.xml`  (see below) XMLSTARLET fails.

First I tried to find the correct XSLT function to get the needed values, which led to this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //field -v . -o "=" -v 'substring("ABCDEFGHIJK",position(),1)' -n input.xml
```

output:

```
 5 =A
 3 =B
 2 =C
 4 =D
 55 =E
 42 =F
```

This made me believe that I should be able to update this XML with the following command:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u //field -x 'substring("ABCDEFGHIJK",position(),1)' input.xmlxmlstarlet ed -u //field -x 'substring("ABCDEFGHIJK",position(),1)' input.xml
```

But I did get:

```
Invalid context position
Segmentation fault
```

I tried using XmlStarlet on Windows 11, and on Ubuntu 20.04, both did a core dump.

I am interested in another solution using XmlStarlet.

FILES

input.xml

```
<root>
   <field> 5 </field>
   <field> 3 </field>
   <field> 2 </field>
   <field> 4 </field>
   <field> 55 </field>
   <field> 42 </field>
</root>
```

(desired) output.xml

```
<root>
   <field>A</field>
   <field>B</field>
   <field>C</field>
   <field>D</field>
   <field>E</field>
   <field>F</field>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position()` works with `xmlstarlet select`'s `-m (--match)` option (i.e. `xsl:for-each`) which determines the context position.

```sh
xmlstarlet select --indent -t \
  -e '{name(*)}' \
    -m '//field' -e '{name()}' -v 'substring("ABCDEFGHIJK",position(),1)' \
file.xml
```

With `xmlstarlet edit`'s `-u (--update)` you can use a sibling node count, e.g.

```sh
xmlstarlet edit -O \
  -u '//field' -x 'substring("ABCDEFGHIJK",1+count(preceding-sibling::field),1)' \
file.xml
```

or

```sh
xmlstarlet edit -O \
  -u '//field' -x 'substring("ABCDEFGHIJK",count(preceding-sibling::* | self::*),1)' \
file.xml
```

Each of these commands produces the desired output. Line continuation chars added for readability.

Comment: The answer produces the desired result, but I still think it's a bug.   Reporting this bug seems a waste of time (see: https://sourceforge.net/p/xmlstar/bugs/stats/)

Comment: I have come to think of this kind of behaviour as *undefined results* (as they say at [opengroup.org](https://www.opengroup.org/)). Given the complexity of XML, XPath, XSLT, and a large number of `xmlstarlet` command-line options the expectations of developers and users don't always align.